# Cannot understand this Swift controller

Tags: ios, swift

I'm learning Swift and I have a controller that use bluetooth to manage a BLE peripheral.
I cannot understand some details, the full code is [here](http://anasimtiaz.com/?p=201) 
I'm writing between code my questions

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate
 {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var stateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tempLabel: UILabel!
    var centralManager : CBCentralManager!
    var sensorTagPeripheral : CBPeripheral!
```

Here I understand: I declare two variable with CBCentralManager and CBPeripheral type, and now the two variable are equal to nil.

```
    // IR Temp UUIDs
    let IRTemperatureServiceUUID = CBUUID(string: "F000AA00-0451-4000-B000-000000000000")
    let IRTemperatureDataUUID   = CBUUID(string: "F000AA01-0451-4000-B000-000000000000")
    let IRTemperatureConfigUUID = CBUUID(string: "F000AA02-0451-4000-B000-000000000000")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

Here I assign to the variable centralManager an instance of CBCentralManager class, but I cannot understand why I'm passing the delegate.

```
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager!) {
        if central.state == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn {
            // Scan for peripherals if BLE is turned on
            central.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
            self.stateLabel.text = "Searching for BLE Devices"
        }
        else {
            // Can have different conditions for all states if needed - print generic message for now
            println("Bluetooth switched off or not initialized")
        }
    }

    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!, advertisementData: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, RSSI: NSNumber!) {

        let deviceName = "SensorTag"
        let nameOfDeviceFound = (advertisementData as NSDictionary).objectForKey(CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey) as? NSString

        if (nameOfDeviceFound == deviceName) {
            // Update Status Label
            self.stateLabel.text = "Sensor Tag Found"

            // Stop scanning
            self.centralManager.stopScan()
            // Set as the peripheral to use and establish connection
            self.sensorTagPeripheral = peripheral
            self.sensorTagPeripheral.delegate = self
            self.centralManager.connectPeripheral(peripheral, options: nil)
        }
        else {
            self.stateLabel.text = "Sensor Tag NOT Found"
        }
    }

    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!, didConnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!) {
        self.stateLabel.text = "Discovering peripheral services"
        peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
    }

    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!, error: NSError!) {
        self.stateLabel.text = "Disconnected"
        central.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
    }

    // Check if the service discovered is a valid IR Temperature Service
    func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didDiscoverServices error: NSError!) {
        self.stateLabel.text = "Looking at peripheral services"
        for service in peripheral.services {
            let thisService = service as! CBService
            if service.UUID == IRTemperatureServiceUUID {
                // Discover characteristics of IR Temperature Service
                peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, forService: thisService)
            }
            // Uncomment to print list of UUIDs
            //println(thisService.UUID)
        }
    }


    // Enable notification and sensor for each characteristic of valid service
    func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService service: CBService!, error: NSError!) {

        // update status label
        self.stateLabel.text = "Enabling sensors"

        // 0x01 data byte to enable sensor
        var enableValue = 1
        let enablyBytes = NSData(bytes: &enableValue, length: sizeof(UInt8))

        // check the uuid of each characteristic to find config and data characteristics
        for charateristic in service.characteristics {
            let thisCharacteristic = charateristic as! CBCharacteristic
            // check for data characteristic
            if thisCharacteristic.UUID == IRTemperatureDataUUID {
                // Enable Sensor Notification
                self.sensorTagPeripheral.setNotifyValue(true, forCharacteristic: thisCharacteristic)
            }
            // check for config characteristic
            if thisCharacteristic.UUID == IRTemperatureConfigUUID {
                // Enable Sensor
                self.sensorTagPeripheral.writeValue(enablyBytes, forCharacteristic: thisCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithResponse)
            }
        }

    }

    func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didUpdateValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic!, error: NSError!) {

        self.stateLabel.text = "Connected"

        if characteristic.UUID == IRTemperatureDataUUID {
            // Convert NSData to array of signed 16 bit values
            let dataBytes = characteristic.value
            let dataLength = dataBytes.length
            var dataArray = [Int16](count: dataLength, repeatedValue: 0)
            dataBytes.getBytes(&dataArray, length: dataLength * sizeof(Int16))

            // Element 1 of the array will be ambient temperature raw value
            let ambientTemperature = Double(dataArray[1])/128

            // Display on the temp label
            self.tempLabel.text = NSString(format: "%.2f", ambientTemperature) as String
        }
    }
}
```

Here is basically the core of my question: I understand that these function are required by the protocol, but who call these functions? For example, who is calling the function "centralManager" and why I have some function with the same name but with different attributes?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

> Here I assign to the variable centralManager an instance of
>   CBCentralManager class, but I cannot understand why I'm passing the
>   delegate.

You are assigning the `delegate` so that the `centralManager` knows who to call.  It uses this pointer to your `HomeViewController` to call the `centralManager*` methods.

For example, when the `centralManager` has updated its state, it tells your `viewController` by calling through the delegate pointer (i.e. a pointer to your `HomeViewController`:

```
delegate.centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: self)
```

passing a pointer to itself through the `central` parameter.

> Here is basically the core of my question: I understand that these
>   function are required by the protocol, but who call these functions?

The `centralManager*` functions are called by the `centralManager` object.  It has a pointer to your `HomeViewController`.  You passed `self`.  The `sensorTagPeripheral` calls the `peripheral*` functions, again through the object pointer `self` that you passed as the `delegate`.

> why I have some function with the same name but with different
>   attributes?

They aren't the same function.  They are different because they have different parameters.

In Swift, functions are defined by their names, the number and types of parameters, their return types, and the external names of the parameters.  For example, here are two versions of add, both defined and both can be called.  Notice that the external parameter names are used when they are called.  This is how Swift tells the two functions apart:

```
func add(first x: Int, second y: Int) -> Int {
    return x + y
}

func add(one a: Int, two b: Int) -> Int {
    return a + b
}

let x = add(first: 3, second: 4)
let y = add(one: 3, two: 4)
```

Here's a question you didn't ask:

> How does the centralManager object know you've implemented the
>   functions it is going to call?

Notice when you defined your `HomeViewController` class, you declared that it implements the `CBCentralManagerDelegate` protocol.  This protocol defines the interface of the `centralManager*` functions you must implement.  If you don't, the Swift compiler will give you an error saying that you don't conform to `CBCentralManagerDelegate`.  Furthermore, only if you implement this protocol can you pass `self` as the delegate.

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate
```

Comment: Additionally, Swift considers the return type of a function when determining uniqueness, so you can have two function s with the same name and input parameter definitions but different return types.

Answer (score 0):

`centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)`
`Classname(...)` init an instance of the class. In your code, it's a `CBCentralManager` class.It sets self(your view controller) to be the `delegate` of the instance which means when this CBCentralManager's instance finished doing something  for your view controller, it will pass some information to your view controller through the delegate methods which you should implement in your view controller.